# Image as a Texture in HoloLens -Issue

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, textures, hololens

Good evening,

Recently I was trying to create an app in Unity where with a button I could open an image or a pdf while the app remains open and running. I tried to do it with Unity, and I didn't see any problem. However, when I used the HoloLens emulator, every time I did it the app opens the file but then closes.

I thought that maybe if I defined several 2D Empty Objects (as Images, Raw Images...) the app would still run while doing this. To do this, I used the WWW class and the example of the Unity Scripting API.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

However, I don't know why when I run the app the Image doesn't change... I also tried the SetTexture() method it still doesn't work. So I was wondering if you have encountered the same problem, and if you could help me to solve it out.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking up the following post: [change texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393782/how-to-change-texture-of-game-object-in-unity)

It comes down to defining a gameobject, making a prefab out of the Image and setting the material of the prefab. You can easily make new materials by importing an image or making one using projects tab>Create>Material. You could try making 2 Materials with different colors to test it.

It could also be code that needs to be run using UWP outside of the editor, if that's the case, you could use

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
//Put your code here.
#endif
```